# How can I favorite [java*] while excluding [javascript]?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, search, wildcards

Let's say I want to follow all Java related questions on Stack Overflow. I decide to favorite **[java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java*)**.

[image: Tag search for java*]

Everything seems to be working fine. My search includes questions about [java](/questions/tagged/java), [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx), [javadoc](/questions/tagged/javadoc) and...

[image: Javascript tag]

oh. [It also includes Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/245062/3357935).

In Regex I could use `^` as a `NOT` character, but sadly `java[^s]` is not a valid option for favoriting tags.

### Is there an equivalent of Regex's NOT character `^` for tag favoriting*? If not, can the option be added?

<sub>*Originally my question mistakenly referred to tag *searching* instead of tag *favoriting*. I apologize for the inconvenience.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

As per the **Advance Search Tips** in the [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page, by using `-[tag]` to exclude the not needed tags.

> [image: Advance Search Tips]

So in your case you case use `[java*]-[javascript]`, but it is not returning the expected result. As I found in this [answer](/a/259916/), you can use [`[java*]-[javascript] is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava*%5D-%5Bjavascript%5D+is%3Aq) to get your expected result.

> [image: Exclude JavaScript]

Incase if you want to exclude all JavaScript related tags (like javascript-events, javascript-objects), you can append * with that exclude tags `[java*]-[javascript*] is:q`

**Update:**

For favoriting the Java tags related tab, use the **[java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java*)** and in the URL remove the exclude tags name and append those in the end as with **not** like `not javascript not javascript-objects not ...`

Comment: Does this work when favoriting a tag?

Comment: For favoriting tag, I didn't find any work around. Manual editing will help, see my **Update:** block